# How do I enable HTTPS on my AWS EC2 Instance running a Docker Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, https, aws-certificate-manager

I am running a Spring Boot Application (as a RESTful Webservice) **dockerized** in an **EC2 Instance**. If I start the container, everything is working fine, but only with **HTTP**. `e.g. http://ec2-54-93-55.eu-central...com`

I already tried setting up the Security Groups of my EC2 Instance, where I enabled HTTPS, but it still does not work.

Now I want to add a SSL Certificate to my Instance with the AWS Certificate Manager. The problem is now, that I need a hosted domain for this and I can not use the Domain of my EC2 Instance.

I tried setting it up as `api.mydomain.com` and it is verified now. How can I now connect my EC2 Instance with this domain?

I tried creating an Alias in Route 53 by routing api.mydomain.com to the EC2 public DNS. But this did not work too.

Comment: Please comment, if more information is needed. I will quickly add them to the post.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to attach an ACM public certificate to your EC2 instance as they are required to be attached to either one of these resources:

- [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)
- [Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/).

Once these are configured you will need to update the DNS record on your hosting provider to target the CNAME of whichever of these resources they use.

If you were using Route 53 as your hosting provider you would [add your record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html) to the public hosted zone for that domain, however this process is slightly different for each DNS provider.